# Combine two DateListPlots and retain a time axis

Tags: plotting

I am trying to combine two DateListPlots to produce a single chart with 2 y-axis. 
There is an example here with regular Plots and I have tried to adapt it for time based data
    https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html

The code below creates smallMeasurements and bigMeasurements, plots each on its own graph, rescales one so they can be seen on the same chart, and then combines them.

The problem I cannot fix is that on combining the charts the X-Axis no longer displays time. Does anyone know some magic to fix this?

```
timesSteps = Map[Function[AbsoluteTime[{2014, 1, 1, 9, #, 0}]], Range[0, 480, 10]];
values = 1 + N[Sin[2*Pi *Mod[timesSteps/60, 360]/360]];

smallMeasurements = ArrayReshape[Riffle[timesSteps, values], {Length[values], 2}];
bigMeasurements = ArrayReshape[Riffle[timesSteps, 1000*(2 - values)], {Length[values], 2}];

smallPlot = DateListPlot[smallMeasurements]
bigPlot = DateListPlot[bigMeasurements];

smallRange = ReplaceAll[PlotRange, AbsoluteOptions[smallPlot, PlotRange]][[2]];
bigRange = ReplaceAll[PlotRange, AbsoluteOptions[bigPlot, PlotRange]][[2]];

leftTicks = N[FindDivisions[smallRange, 5]];
rightTicks = Quiet[Transpose[{leftTicks, Map[Function[ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm]], Rescale[leftTicks, smallRange, bigRange]]}]] ;

bigPlotRescaled = ReplaceAll[bigPlot, Graphics[graph_, s___] -> Graphics[GeometricTransformation[graph, RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, bigRange}, {{0, 1}, smallRange}]], s]]

Show[smallPlot, bigPlotRescaled, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
FrameTicks -> {{leftTicks, rightTicks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image: smallPlot]

[image: bigPlotRescaled]

[image: Combined]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem arises due to the following option in the final `Show` command:

```
FrameTicks -> {{leftTicks, rightTicks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

Instead of `{Automatic, Automatic}` you should give explicit ticks specification taken from any of two `DateListPlot`s (if they have identical ticks):

```
FrameTicks -> {{leftTicks, rightTicks}, Options[smallPlot, FrameTicks][[1, 2, 2]]}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, thats exactly the sort of trick I had hoped for but failed to find in the documentation.

Comment: Later I added a legend and the code above broke. If you need to do the same the answer is [here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/reading-options-from-datelistplots-with-legends)